# Integral, Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x) >0$ for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let A be a Lebesgue measurable set such that $\int_{A} f =0$. Prove $m(A) = 0$.

wlog we can assume $f(x)>0$ everywhere define $A_{n}={x \in A: f(x) > \frac{1}{n}}$
so since $f(x) > 0$ everywhere, $\int_{A_n} f dm \leq \int_{A} fdm = 0$. Then it is easy to see that A is a countable union of sets of measure 0, so A has measure 0 in this case.

My question is: why do we need A to be Lebesgue measurable? doesn't the above proof works for any measurable set? I still don't see the difference.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think the difference is between *Lebesgue measurable* and *measurable* in this context?

Comment: @Mariano: that is it endowed with the Lebesgue measure, so I see that the argument works in general with any measure.

Answer (score 2):

When they write $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, the measure on $\mathbb{R}$ hasn't been specified, so it's assumed to be Lebesgue measure.  If you had $L^1(\mu)$ for an arbitrary measure $\mu$ your argument would work just as well.

Comment: Yes. this will work for any measure $\mu$ provided $f \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$